# handling timestamps without seconds in some rows using R

Tags: r, timestamp

My data set truncates the seconds if it is `:00`
For example :

```
Time_TS
2022-06-22T18:48:58
2022-06-22T18:48:59
2022-06-22T18:49
2022-06-22T18:49:01
2022-06-22T18:49:59
2022-06-22T18:50
2022-06-22T18:50:01
2022-06-22T18:50:02
```

Hence rows 3 and 6 result in an `NA` when I use the strptime fnction:

```
source1$Time_TSS<-strptime(source1$Time_TS, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

I tried the method suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70304425/r-datetime-series-missing-values/70304571#comment124278515_70304580), but it doesn't seem to work.
Any other ideas?

Comment: You could probably just paste ```:00``` for any Time_TS that is under the desired character length (19 I think?)

Comment: @Silentdevildoll I thought about that, but dint want to take the risk of missing some edge cases where it would be different characters. 
But I guess im just being paranoid :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
dat$Time_TS <- gsub("(T\\d{2}:\\d{2})$", "\\1:00", dat$Time_TS)
dat
#               Time_TS
# 1 2022-06-22T18:48:58
# 2 2022-06-22T18:48:59
# 3 2022-06-22T18:49:00
# 4 2022-06-22T18:49:01
# 5 2022-06-22T18:49:59
# 6 2022-06-22T18:50:00
# 7 2022-06-22T18:50:01
# 8 2022-06-22T18:50:02
strptime(dat$Time_TS, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
# [1] "2022-06-22 18:48:58 EDT" "2022-06-22 18:48:59 EDT"
# [3] "2022-06-22 18:49:00 EDT" "2022-06-22 18:49:01 EDT"
# [5] "2022-06-22 18:49:59 EDT" "2022-06-22 18:50:00 EDT"
# [7] "2022-06-22 18:50:01 EDT" "2022-06-22 18:50:02 EDT"
```

Comment: FYI, if you're confident enough in the rest of the strings, one could also use `paste0(dat$Time_TS, ifelse(nchar(dat$Time_TS) == 16, ":00", ""))`.

Comment: I did use the `paste0` but I would prefer the reg ex since it would take anything of any length.