# Apply function to vector of char elementwise

Tags: r, date, apply

I have a vector of dates which I imported from excel and it comes in a very weird format. Some of them come as char as `dd/mm/yyyy` and some come as a char as, for instance, `45265` which is the number corresponding to this date in excel.

I want to apply a function to convert this vector to proper dates in R. The solution I tried returns an error and I cannot understand it.

```
t1=c("14/02/2020", "17/02/2020", "18/02/2020", "19/02/2020", "20/02/2020", 
     "21/02/2020", "26/02/2020", "27/02/2020", "28/02/2020", "43864", 
     "43893", "43924", "43954", "43985", "44077")
lapply(t1,function(x) ifelse(grepl("/",x),dmy(x),as.Date(as.numeric(x),origin='1900-01-01')))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. most of what you want to do can be done as a vector, no need to apply;
2. `ifelse` is class-unsafe, trying to use it with `Date`-class (or `POSIXt`-class), for example, will strip the class and return numbers. See [How to prevent ifelse() from turning Date objects into numeric objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6668963/3358272).

I suggest this as an alternative:

```r
out <- rep(as.Date(NA), length(t1))
out[grepl("/", t1)] <- as.Date(t1[grepl("/", t1)], format = "%d/%m/%Y")
out[is.na(out)] <- as.Date(as.numeric(t1[is.na(out)]), origin = "1900-01-01")
out
#  [1] "2020-02-14" "2020-02-17" "2020-02-18" "2020-02-19" "2020-02-20" "2020-02-21" "2020-02-26" "2020-02-27"
#  [9] "2020-02-28" "2020-02-05" "2020-03-05" "2020-04-05" "2020-05-05" "2020-06-05" "2020-09-05"
```

If you have more candidate formats, you might consider https://stackoverflow.com/a/52319606/3358272 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/70304571/3358272, which iterates over possible formats (in a similar way) and attempts to convert them all until completion (or exhaustion).

An alternative to using `base::ifelse` (which strips class) is to use either `dplyr::if_else` or `data.table::fifelse`, which might be simpler if you are using either package for other uses. Note that they will run both methods on all of `t1`, so you will get warnings (both implementations).

```r
if_else(grepl("/", t1), lubridate::dmy(t1), as.Date(as.numeric(t1), origin = "1900-01-01"))
# WARN [2023-05-17 09:54:01] {"msg":"uncaught warning","warning":" 6 failed to parse.","where":["ccbr()","if_else(grepl(\"/\", t1), lubridat","lubridate::dmy(t1)"],"pid":"39316"}
# WARN [2023-05-17 09:54:01] {"msg":"uncaught warning","warning":"NAs introduced by coercion","where":["ccbr()","if_else(grepl(\"/\", t1), lubridat","as.Date(as.numeric(t1), origin ="],"pid":"39316"}
#  [1] "2020-02-14" "2020-02-17" "2020-02-18" "2020-02-19" "2020-02-20" "2020-02-21" "2020-02-26" "2020-02-27"
#  [9] "2020-02-28" "2020-02-05" "2020-03-05" "2020-04-05" "2020-05-05" "2020-06-05" "2020-09-05"
data.table::fifelse(grepl("/", t1), lubridate::dmy(t1), as.Date(as.numeric(t1), origin = "1900-01-01"))
# WARN [2023-05-17 09:54:11] {"msg":"uncaught warning","warning":" 6 failed to parse.","where":["ccbr()","data.table::fifelse(grepl(\"/\", t","lubridate::dmy(t1)"],"pid":"39316"}
# WARN [2023-05-17 09:54:11] {"msg":"uncaught warning","warning":"NAs introduced by coercion","where":["ccbr()","data.table::fifelse(grepl(\"/\", t","as.Date(as.numeric(t1), origin ="],"pid":"39316"}
#  [1] "2020-02-14" "2020-02-17" "2020-02-18" "2020-02-19" "2020-02-20" "2020-02-21" "2020-02-26" "2020-02-27"
#  [9] "2020-02-28" "2020-02-05" "2020-03-05" "2020-04-05" "2020-05-05" "2020-06-05" "2020-09-05"
```

This can be suppressed by wrapping the whole `if_else`/`fifelse` with `suppressWarnings`.