# Fomart date with date_parser

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, tidyverse, mutate

I'm using R to extract data from multiple pdf files. After extracting this data, I need to format a field of type date.  Dates came from pdf files in various formats

```
data = c( "1/10/2022 2:36:00 pm",
  "1/11/2022 12:47:00 pm",
  "1/12/2022 9:47:00 am",
  "1/13/2022 9:21:00 am",
  "1/14/2022 12:59:00 pm",
  "1/10/2022 2:39:00 pm",
  "1/11/2022 12:46:00 pm",
  "1/12/2022 9:48:00 am",
  "1/13/2022 9:22:00 am",
  "1/14/2022 1:00:00 pm",
  "1/10/2022 2:40:00 pm",
  "1/11/2022 12:45:00 pm",
  "1/12/2022 9:49:00 am",
  "1/13/2022 9:23:00 am",
  "1/14/2022 1:01:00 pm",
  "1/10/2022 2:42:00 pm",
  "1/11/2022 12:44:00 pm",
  "1/12/2022 9:50:00 am",
  "1/13/2022 9:24:00 am",
  "1/14/2022 1:02:00 pm",
  "1/10/2022 2:44:00 pm",
  "1/11/2022 12:43:00 pm",
  "1/12/2022 9:51:00 am",
  "1/13/2022 9:25:00 am",
  "1/14/2022 1:03:00 pm",
  "10/01/2022 14:36:00",
  "11/01/2022 12:47:00",
  "12/01/2022 09:47:00",
  "13/01/2022 09:21:00",
  "14/01/2022 12:59:00",
  "10/01/2022 14:39:00",
  "11/01/2022 12:46:00",
  "12/01/2022 09:48:00",
  "13/01/2022 09:22:00",
  "14/01/2022 13:00:00",
  "10/01/2022 14:40:00",
  "11/01/2022 12:45:00",
  "12/01/2022 09:49:00",
  "13/01/2022 09:23:00",
  "14/01/2022 13:01:00",
  "10/01/2022 14:42:00")
df <- data.frame(data)
```

I tried as follows

```
date_parser <- function(d) {
  if (endsWith(d, "m")) {
    as.POSIXct(d, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
  } else {
    as.POSIXct(d, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
  }
}

df = df%>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(data = date_parser(data))
```

I get this error message

Error in mutate:In argument: data_hora_leitura_coc08 = date_parser(data_hora_leitura_coc08).In row 1732.Caused by error in `if (endsWith(d, "m")) missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Also, some dates come out as "NA" How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data has seconds, so you need to add `%S` to each of your formats.

```r
date_parser <- function(d) {
  if (endsWith(d, "m")) {
    as.POSIXct(d, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
  } else {
    as.POSIXct(d, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
  }
}
```

```r
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(data = date_parser(data))
# # A tibble: 41 × 1
# # Rowwise: 
#    data               
#    <dttm>             
#  1 2022-01-10 14:36:00
#  2 2022-01-11 12:47:00
#  3 2022-01-12 09:47:00
#  4 2022-01-13 09:21:00
#  5 2022-01-14 12:59:00
#  6 2022-01-10 14:39:00
#  7 2022-01-11 12:46:00
#  8 2022-01-12 09:48:00
#  9 2022-01-13 09:22:00
# 10 2022-01-14 13:00:00
# # ℹ 31 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: Some dates are still coming out in NA format. How do I share all date records with you? There are more than 6,000 lines

Comment: Find the ones that are `NA` in the output and share some samples of the originals of those. (You may want to do `df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(data2 = date_parser(data)) %>% filter(is.na(data2))` and take some samples from that. You may also want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52319606/3358272 (dates), https://stackoverflow.com/a/70304571/3358272 (POSIXct) for ways to handle multiple "candidate formats" of your timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

`lubridate` does exactly what you want. Try

```
df %>% 
   mutate(parsed_data = if_else(endsWith(data, "m"), mdy_hms(data), dmy_hms(data)))
```

Answer (score 0):

With `parse_date_time`

```
library(lubridate)

df %>% mutate(new = parse_date_time(data, 
  orders=c("mdY IMS p", "dmY HMS", "mdY IM p", "dmY HM")))
                    data                 new
1   1/10/2022 2:36:00 pm 2022-01-10 14:36:00
2  1/11/2022 12:47:00 pm 2022-01-11 12:47:00
3   1/12/2022 9:47:00 am 2022-01-12 09:47:00
4   1/13/2022 9:21:00 am 2022-01-13 09:21:00
5  1/14/2022 12:59:00 pm 2022-01-14 12:59:00
6    10/01/2022 14:36:00 2022-01-10 14:36:00
7    11/01/2022 12:47:00 2022-11-01 12:47:00
8    12/01/2022 09:47:00 2022-12-01 09:47:00
9    13/01/2022 09:21:00 2022-01-13 09:21:00
10   14/01/2022 12:59:00 2022-01-14 12:59:00
11    12/2/2022 10:16 am 2022-12-02 10:16:00
12   12/11/2022 12:28 pm 2022-12-11 12:28:00
13      07/12/2022 10:49 2022-07-12 10:49:00
14      2/1/2023 5:10 pm 2023-02-01 17:10:00
15      28/01/2023 10:39 2023-01-28 10:39:00
16      2/1/2023 9:58 am 2023-02-01 09:58:00
17      06/12/2022 09:20 2022-06-12 09:20:00
18      07/12/2022 10:08 2022-07-12 10:08:00
19      08/12/2022 07:48 2022-08-12 07:48:00
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(data = c("1/10/2022 2:36:00 pm", "1/11/2022 12:47:00 pm", 
"1/12/2022 9:47:00 am", "1/13/2022 9:21:00 am", "1/14/2022 12:59:00 pm", 
"10/01/2022 14:36:00", "11/01/2022 12:47:00", "12/01/2022 09:47:00", 
"13/01/2022 09:21:00", "14/01/2022 12:59:00", "12/2/2022 10:16 am", 
"12/11/2022 12:28 pm", "07/12/2022 10:49", "2/1/2023 5:10 pm", 
"28/01/2023 10:39", "2/1/2023 9:58 am", "06/12/2022 09:20", "07/12/2022 10:08", 
"08/12/2022 07:48")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))
```

Comment: Warning message:
There was 1 warning in `mutate()`.
ℹ In argument: `new = parse_date_time(...)`.
Caused by warning:
!  2979 failed to parse.

Comment: @FranciscoRibeiro ... means you have dates other than the ones you showed us. Try to find rows that deviate from the pattern. May even be that you have rows that can't be interpreted as a proper date.

Comment: Some dates are still coming out in NA format. How do I share all date records with you? There are more than 6,000 lines

Comment: @FranciscoRibeiro You can try to search for differing patterns, e.g. `df$data[!grepl(".*/.*/.* .*:.*:", df$data)]` and post those with `dput(head(df$data[!grepl(".*/.*/.* .*:.*:", df$data)], 10))`

Comment: "12/2/2022 10:16 am", "12/11/2022 12:28 pm", "07/12/2022 10:49", "2/1/2023 5:10 pm", "28/01/2023 10:39", "2/1/2023 9:58 am" , "06/12/2022 09:20", "07/12/2022 10:08", "08/12/2022 07:48

Comment: @FranciscoRibeiro These are without seconds, should work now with edit.

Comment: Separated in a dataframe, the times that contain am | pm.

10/1/2022 2:36:00 pm,
11/1/2022 12:47:00 pm,
12/1/2022 9:47:00 am

This am|pm pattern in some cases I get NA return

Comment: @FranciscoRibeiro These am/pm don't differ from the ones already present and should not pose a problem.